# How to access the key's value of Ant select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, multi-select

I need to get the `item ID` of the selected `item`, In my case the user types in the input and gets results from an API in form of array that iterates the `<Option>` as below.

```
<Select
    mode="multiple"
    style={{ width: '100%' }}
    placeholder="Select Invoices"
    defaultValue={[]}
    onChange={handle_select_invoices}
    optionLabelProp="label"
    onSearch={search_invoice_by_number}
    >
    {
    invoices.map((el,index) => {
        return <Option key={el.invoice_id} value={el.invoice_number}></Option>
    })
    }
</Select>
```

When user select an option, the `handle_select_invoices` is fired. It takes two params `value` and `key`.

```
const handle_select_invoices =(value,key) => {
    console.log(' ************** IDS ****************')
    console.log(key)
}

function search_invoice_by_number(value) {
    var data={'invoice_number':value};
    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/get_invoice_by_number',data).then(
        response => {

            if(response.data.length > 0){
                set_invoices(response.data);
            }else{
                set_invoices([]);
            }
        },error =>{
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Error!',
                text: 'Please Contact your software developer',
                icon: 'error',
                confirmButtonText: 'OK'
            })
        }
    )
}
```

**The problem**

When user selects multiple items, the console.log shows an empty `Json` elements and only the last element in the array is filled.

[image: console.log from handle_select_invoices method that is executed on the onChange event]

What is wrong in the code that leads to this result?

Comment: well your code looks fine and it works fine in codesandbox. check here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-carson-xwydd?file=/src/App.js. Anything else you might be doing wrong?  Have you tried removing the closing `</Option>` tag and just do `<Option key={el.invoice_id} value={el.invoice_number} />`

Comment: @UzairRiaz I figured out the problem. but didn't know how to solve it. This is happening because the `invoices` array is getting its value from an `API` so that when i select an option and than search for another option. the `invoices` array is getting new array values. I don't know if you can test it this way.

Comment: could you share `search_invoice_by_number` function? I might try to create your scenario with dummy data.

Comment: what I do in my project is load the full data and `onSearch` I filter it on frontend. If your data is too big, you might have to manually empty the selected options that no longer exist in the new data.

Comment: @UzairRiaz yes the data is too big, I can't let the browser make the filtration. I updated the question

Comment: do you want all the data? If I select `invoice_number` 123, I search something and new data doesn't have 123. Do you want the 123 as well? If yes, you can use `value` instead of `key`? It gives you all the selected values regardless of whether they no longer exist in the select list data. Check here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-carson-xwydd?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @UzairRiaz No, in my case user can only select existing invoices. he searches for an invoice, and in the back-end i filter the data with `where like` query. So i need to get the key 's value which in my case it is the `invoice_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I think I understand what you mean. Here is how I suggest you do it. Use a variable in state that keeps track of `selectedValues`. In select `onChange` just set them in state like `handleChange = values => setSelectedValues(values)`. In search, after you get the new data from the API, filter the `selectedValues` like so:

```
set_invoices(response.data);
const values = selectedValues.filter(value => 
    data.map(i => i.invoice_number).includes(value)
);
setSelectedValues(values); // filter out the values that do not exist in the new data
```

and your select would contain an additional prop `value={selectedValues}`.

Here is a working example with some dummy data: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-carson-xwydd?file=/src/App.js:699-805

Comment: Yeah, this is the best way